Why does Eureka fail to detect new client instances when Spring Boot port is dynamically set to 0?
I have verified that all configurations in both my Spring applications and the Eureka server are correctly set up. However, I am encountering an issue where two instances of my services, which are successfully registering with Eureka, are not appearing on the Eureka dashboard. Below are 2 instances when server.port=0






In the Eureka dashboard:



After providing a static port with



In the Eureka dashboard:

Is there any reason why this is happening? secondly, I can't request these clients i.e.:
String serviceBUrl = "http://INVENTORY-SERVICE/inventory";
List<InventoryResponse> inventoryResponseStocks = webClient
        .get()
        .uri(serviceBUrl, uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(InventoryResponse.class)
        .collectList()
        .block();

Error:
io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsErrorCauseException: Query failed with NXDOMAIN
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(..)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]


Please provide the full exception stacktrace, and post the logging as text, not as screenshots.

Adding @LoadBalanced to enable the client-side loadbalancing capabilities since multiple instances of the inventory service were running. So the calling-service could not resolve any running instance of the inventory service.

On the configuration file for the webClient place the @LoadBalanced since running multiple instances and use WebClient.Builder screenshot of the changes need to do in configuration file
and then call the autowired as
private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
and then just call the webclientbuilder to get the webclient function :
webClientBuilder.build().get().uri()
this would might help in resolving the issues

Try not to post images of code.
